# Basic Block Usage Help on Wordpress

Tags: block-editor

Im very new to wordpress and am trying to get a simple design going for a single page on my site. On the editor page, I get what I want. The design should look similar to this:
[image]

Comment: I don't think this question is related to WordPress, you have more than one post in the pictures, create custom type of recipes (or native wp posts) and set up archive page for these posts, you can use this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/pods/

Comment: I don't even know what the question is.  What specifically are you asking?